# How to make request from web to nw.js app?

Tags: request, desktop-application, node-webkit

I'm developing an application in `nw.js` and also I do have a `website`. I need to do something on `nw app` when an action is done in the `website`. Can we make `requests` to `nw app` from `website` ? Or is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a central database that your remote nw.js apps can talk to. Something with pubsub like redis would do.

Your website would publish something and your NW.js app would subscribe to it.